# Picking certain values in Series as headings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has a column that looks like:

```
Japan
valA
valB
Ghana
valC
valD
...
```

I want to extract the country names from this list and turn them into another column like so:

```
Japan    valA
Japan    valB
Ghana    valC
Ghana    valD
```

I am sure there's an answer for this already on SO, but I haven't been able to find the correct keywords to bring it up.

Right now, I am doing the following, but I then have to drop rows that initially contained the country names:

```
def get_country(row):
    if #decide if it's a country name:
        return row[0]
df['country'] = df.apply(get_country, axis=1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

This seems like a fairly common use case when cleaning data, is there a standard/better way of doing this?

Comment: Is the *val* examples a number or starts with a specific letter or pattern ?

Comment: I actually have a number of use cases, with `val` being numbers in some cases, or fairly random strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can get you started using `map` and `ffill`.

```
def is_country(x): 
    # TODO - fill in the logic for this stub.
    return x in {'Japan', 'Ghana'}

df

       A
0  Japan
1   valA
2   valB
3  Ghana
4   valC
5   valD


df.assign(B=df['A'].where(df['A'].map(is_country)).ffill()).query('A != B')

      A      B
1  valA  Japan
2  valB  Japan
4  valC  Ghana
5  valD  Ghana
```

---

You can use a package like [`pycountry`](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) (or something similar) to validate country names.

```
import pycountry
countries = {x.name for x in pycountry.countries}  # Initialise a set.

def is_country(x): 
    return x in countries
```

Although, with this definition, you can simplify your code to,

```
df.assign(B=df['A'].where(df['A'].isin(countries)).ffill()).query('A != B')
```

And get rid of the `is_country` function entirely.

Comment: i was just about to post about pycountry. +1 :)

Comment: @anky_91 Thank you! First search result for "get country names in python" after all ;-)

Comment: @anky_91 This is the only one I'm aware of, I'm afraid. There might be others, but this suits most purposes. Dealing with countries does come up but not that often.

Answer (score 4):

Using extract

```
new_df = df['col'].str.extract('(val.*)?(.*)').replace('', np.nan).rename(columns = {1:'Country', 0:'Value'})
new_df['Country'] = new_df['Country'].ffill()
new_df.dropna(inplace = True)


    Value   Country
1   valA    Japan
2   valB    Japan
4   valC    Ghana
5   valD    Ghana
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `groupby` + `pd.concat`. You can define `countries` explicitly or use your favourite source.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Japan', 'valA', 'valB', 'Ghana', 'valC', 'valD']})
countries = ['Japan', 'Ghana']

grouper = df['col'].groupby(df['col'].isin(countries).cumsum())    
dfs = (pd.DataFrame({'Country': df_ctry.iat[0], 'Value': df_ctry.iloc[1:]}) \
       for _, df_ctry in grouper)

res = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

print(res)

  Country Value
0   Japan  valA
1   Japan  valB
2   Ghana  valC
3   Ghana  valD
```